# "X" cites as a main influence the many colors

Tags: grammar

This is a sentence from Magoosh GRE:

> Jacob Lawrence cites as a primary influence the many colors and shapes
> of Depression-era Harlem.

My question is why is this sentence grammatically correct? I thought there shall be an "on" following influence. Or, is there any rule in English allowing such omission?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may make more sense if you read the sentence with a different ordering: "Jacob Lawrence cites the many colors and shapes of Depression-era Harlem as a primary influence." You don't need "on" if it's implied elsewhere or somehow understood by the audience. For example, suppose I tell you "J. K. Rowling has cited The Chronicles of Narnia as one of her influences." As long as you know that J. K. Rowling is famous for the Harry Potter series, then you can probably understand that sentence to mean that The Chronicles of Narnia were an influence *on* the Harry Potter series of books.

Comment: @Brandin This is answer-worthy. Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an "on" to the sentence would change its meaning.

> Jacob Lawrence cites as a primary influence the many colors and shapes of Depression-era Harlem.

Here, "the many colors and shapes of Depression-era Harlem" is what is being cited as the primary influence on Jacob Lawrence. Harlem was influencing him.

> Jacob Lawrence cites as a primary influence *on* the many colors and shapes of Depression-era Harlem.

This, however, changes the subject of the influence (and makes the sentence ambiguous/incorrect). Here, "the many colors and shapes of Depression-era Harlem" is said to be influenced by something that Jacob Lawrence has cited. This sentence is ambiguous because it is no longer specifying what is being cited. It could work if you add a something here to specify what that is:

> Jacob Lawrence cites *the area's history* as a primary influence *on* the many colors and shapes of Depression-era Harlem.